# VS 2010: <system.web><compilation debug="false" /></system.web> for non-web-apps?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, web-config, app-config, console-application

In web apps, there are these nodes and attributes:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" />
</system.web>
```

I had read that turning this off in a production environment improves performance.  However, does this exist for non-web-apps like console apps?  We use a console app to host services which make heavy calls to data layer operations and I am wondering if there's a way to tweak it to enhance performance any that we can.

Answer (score 0):

Just build your application in Release mode and all possible optimization will be performed on your code.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446027/c-debug-vs-release-performance) is discussion on stackoverflow about differences and if it have some optimization. Anyway it's better to optimize logic in application instead of some technical optimization.