# Not sure what type it should be

Tags: c#

I want to extract all the sundays in the current month and have this code:

```
 private string GetDatesOfSundays(DateTime DatMonth)
 {
  string sReturn = "";
  int iDayOffset = DatMonth.Day - 1;
  DatMonth = DatMonth.AddDays(System.Convert.ToDouble(-DatMonth.Day + 1));
  DateTime DatMonth2 = DatMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(System.Convert.ToDouble(-1));
  while (DatMonth < DatMonth2)
  {
    if (DatMonth.DayOfWeek == System.DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
      if (sReturn.Length > 0) sReturn += ",";
      sReturn += DatMonth.ToShortDateString();
    }
    DatMonth = DatMonth.AddDays(1.0);
  }
  return sReturn;
}   

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult TradeUKKPISearchesData()
{
  string allSundaysInMonth = GetDatesOfSundays(System.DateTime.Now);  
  //var reportData = _reportingService.GetTradeUKKPISearches();
  //return View(reportData);
}
```

the problem lies with my type string for allSundaysInMonth and is also empty ofcourse. The sReturn is of type string but then again I pass a date(I know :)  ) but what type should allSundaysInMonth be? sReturn does have the correct dates in...I need to display these dates in a dropdown in the view of the controller so the user can select any of the sundays for which he/she needs to run a report for.

thanks

Comment: `IEnumerable<DateTime>` looks good to me

Comment: I tried: IEnumerable<DateTime> allSundaysInMonth = GetDatesOfSundays(System.DateTime.Now); and it gives error Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.DateTime>' :(

Comment: @charlie, you *can* declare your variable as `string` and the method's return type as `IEnumerable<DateTime>`, but don't expect the two to fit together. One is a sequence of dates, the other is a bunch of characters. Not the same types at all, thus you can't assign one to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for `DateTime[]` or `IEnumerable<DateTime>`.

Your method signature should be

```
private IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDatesOfSundays(DateTime DatMonth)
```

or

```
private DateTime[] GetDatesOfSundays(DateTime DatMonth)
```

If you havn't worked with `IEnumerable` go for this

```
private DateTime[] GetDatesOfSundays(DateTime DatMonth)
{
    List<DateTime> lst = new List<DateTime>();

    DatMonth = DatMonth.AddDays(-DatMonth.Day + 1);
    DateTime DatMonth2 = DatMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(System.Convert.ToDouble(-1));

    while (DatMonth < DatMonth2)
    {
        if (DatMonth.DayOfWeek == System.DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            lst.Add(DatMonth);
            DatMonth = DatMonth.AddDays(7);
            continue;
        }

        DatMonth = DatMonth.AddDays(1);
    }

    return lst.ToArray();
}
```

and call it as

```
DateTime[] allSundaysInMonth = GetDatesOfSundays(System.DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Why return an array whan you have just built a list? `IList<DateTime>` would be simpler.

Comment: Just one more question please..I went with the example above, the return lst.ToArray(); contains the correct info but the calling line: DateTime[] allSundaysInMonth = GetDatesOfSundays(System.DateTime.Now);  does not, there is nothing in allSundaysInMonth?

Comment: @charlie_cat: Its working fine at my end. `allSundaysInMonth` gets for this month 4 dates namely 5,12,19,26. I have modified my answer to be more quick. Please check and let me know. Also tell me for which month and year are you trying where you are getting nothing.

Comment: I added the extra two lines but still nothing in my variable yes those are the dates in the return lst.ToArray(); thanks.. something somewhere not right though...i will check my code again. thanks

Comment: @charlie_cat: Is this running in Release or Debug mode?

Comment: release, I see...should it be debug?

Comment: there you go! i changed it to debug mode and voila! thank you so much every body!!

Comment: @charlie_cat: The reason is this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446027/c-sharp-debug-vs-release-performance. Read AZ answer's first point. That is reason for your problem. If you want to be in release mode. after this `DateTime[] allSundaysInMonth = GetDatesOfSundays(System.DateTime.Now);` do this `allSundaysInMonth = allSundaysInMonth;`

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
private IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDatesOfSundays(DateTime DatMonth)
{
    int iDayOffset = DatMonth.Day - 1;   
    DatMonth = DatMonth.AddDays(System.Convert.ToDouble(-DatMonth.Day + 1));
    DateTime DatMonth2 =
        DatMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(System.Convert.ToDouble(-1));
    while (DatMonth < DatMonth2)
    {
        if (DatMonth.DayOfWeek == System.DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            yield return DatMonth;
        }

        DatMonth = DatMonth.AddDays(1.0);
    }
}
```

I would be tempted to rewrite your function as an extension somthing like this

```
public static IEnumerable<Datetime> DaysOfMonth(
    this DateTime any,
    DayOfWeek day)
{
    // start at first of month
    var candidate = new DateTime(any.Year, any.Month, 1);

    var offset = (int)day - (int)candidate.DayOfWeek;

    if (offset < 0)
    {
        offset += 7
    }

    candidate = candidate.AddDays(offset);

    while (cadidate.Month == any.Month)
    {
        yield return candidate;
        candidate = candidate.AddDays(7.0)
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like this

```
var allSundaysInMonth = DateTime.Now.DaysOfMonth(DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

---

If you want to convert an `IEnumerable<DateTime>` to a `string` you could do this,

```
var listOfDates = string.Join<DateTime>(", ", allSundaysInMonth);
```

using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) `string.Join` overload

---

If you really want the days as a `DateTime[]` you could do this (but there is no need)

```
DateTime[] allSundaysInMonth = GetDatesOfSundays(DateTime.Now).ToArray();
```

or for my extension example

```
var allSundaysInMonth = DateTime.Now.DaysOfMonth(DayOfWeek.Sunday).ToArray();
```

Comment: oooo ok sorry I have never worked with IEnumerable..I see/understand now..thanks!

Comment: @charlie_cat learn about `IEnumerable` so you can unlock the power of linq

Comment: @charlie_cat I optimised the extension method to avoid needless iteration.

Comment: @charlie_cat tweaked for the last time.

Comment: I opted to use the DateTime[], I understand that better but have one more question on the calling line: DateTime[] allSundaysInMonth = GetDatesOfSundays(System.DateTime.Now); when I debug and hover over allSundaysInMonth there is nothing and in DateTime[] I do not get the correct values as shoud be, and I get in return lst.ToArray();? thanks so much

Comment: @charlie_cat `.ToArray()` is an extension to any `IEnumerable` so you can put `.ToArray()` on the end of my function call and it will give you an array instead. As for your specific problem, I suspect you need to execute the line to assign a value to the variable. Try stepping to the next line and looking at the value of `allSundaysInMonth`

Comment: I did step onto the next line though and still when i hover over the dateTime part I get a minValue,MaxValue,No,Today and uctToday?? and on my variable there is nothing...very odd

Comment: @charlie_cat those are the properties of the DateTime structure.