# Deployment in Debug mode and Release mode

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I need your help in understanding this.

What is the major difference in deploying a dot net application in Debug mode and Release  Mode.?
How to they differ from the developer's perspective and also the efficiency and performance of the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a similar question
You can go through it to understand the difference
[What is the difference between Debug and Release in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367884/debug-release-difference)
[Debug vs. Release performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446027/c-sharp-debug-vs-release-performance)