# User testing in Debug mode - why not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testing, user-testing

What are the negatives for deployment using debug and performing user testing on the debug release.

I'd always use Release deployment to a User Test environment, but I'm just trying to put together a list of why you should do this and not deploy using debug.

Comment: You can release whatever it pleases you. Just make sure that you test it.

Comment: re performance, Hans has a great summary here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043821/performance-differences-between-debug-and-release-builds

Answer (score 2):

Testing should be done on the software that will be delivered to production. If you deliver a release version to production, testing a debug version is not as good as testing the release version.

Answer (score 0):

You can release whatever you want, but you have to test exactly what you release (not some other form). Where as why you should prefer Release mode - [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446027/c-sharp-debug-vs-release-performance)