# Real difference between "Release" and "Debug" builds in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, jit

After studying the actual difference between "Debug" and "Release" build configurations in a default ASP.NET Core (.NET 5) project the only *actual* difference I can spot is the presence of "Optimize" checkbox in "Release" (equivalent of `<Optimize>true</Optimize>` setting in csproj).

That's it. Nothing else. Both generate same PDB debug symbols, both have almost the same warning settings, etc. etc... Nothing else that affects performance.

Question 1: Is it really the only thing that differs?

Question 2: Does this setting have any effect on the *actual* further compilation by JIT?

Comment: see also: [Debug vs. Release performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446027/debug-vs-release-performance)

Comment: @luuk that question is from 2010 and talks about the old Framework, the old compiler, the old JIT etc. None of that is relevant with .NET Core which uses RyuJIT and Roslyn.

Comment: The basic differences between debug and release will still  be the same....