# Alpaca Stock API Timeout when Pulling Historic Data When Published but not when in Debug

Tags: c#, stock, alpaca

I have a basic console app that daily pulls a long list of stock values for the day.

When I run it in debug it works fine.  However, when I publish it I get a lot of timeout errors.   What would be different with a published app then running from the IDE?   Is there a configuration difference in port/communication timeouts when published vs running in the IDE?

This is written in C# visual Studio 2022

I can mostly make it work by adding in a thread.sleep every 100 requests or so but it is dramatically slower.

Just looking for some ideas on where the discrepancy might exist.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with Alpaca, they do limit how many API calls you can make. According to their FAQs it's 200/min (Alpaca Docs: https://alpaca.markets/support/usage-limit-api-calls)

So any difference between debug and a publish app will be because of performance/optimizations. From some research, it does appear that debug mode is slower and that there are some optimizations that are built into a published app.

Here are a couple StackOverflow posts about it that might shed some more light on performance differences between debug and published:

- [Debug vs. Release performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446027/debug-vs-release-performance)
- [Performance differences between debug and release builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043821/performance-differences-between-debug-and-release-builds)

Comment: Appreciate the feedback Sir I may just need to go ahead and force those delays in.  I do find it odd that in debug I absolutely get through the whole list of 11,000 I pull in 5 min or less.   Ah well just means I need to kick it off a little earlier.   Thanks again

Comment: Adding those delays is probably the best way to deal with your situation. I have to include those delays in my trading bot or else i will get timeout errors. I would recommend doing some experimenting how small of a delay you need to add. I only had to add a delay of 50 milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you Sir.  appreciate all the feedback.   I will give that a shot and post back with the results.

Comment: Just a quick follow up.   It looks like 50 ms did the job.  Thank you again